# Find all points that maximizes the directional derivative

Tags: derivatives, vectors, partial-derivative

Hello got stuck on this question, would love for some insight.

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nX4B.png)

The answer is that all points lie on the line y = x + 1 but I am unaware on how to get that outcome.

Comment: Take the gradient of your function.  Then find the set of points that have the correct direction.

Comment: That's exactly what the question is asking, to find the points and I am unaware of how to do so, which is the point of me asking it here. I did find the gradients but that just led me to a dead-end

Comment: Also, images which are links are frowned upon. In this case, you can remove the image and use [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?noredirect=1&lq=1) mathjax guide to format it in the question.

Comment: First, I suggest you copy your question into the body of the text.  Use latex.  Then I suggest you tell us what you think you need to do.  And what work you have done along that path.  Then perhaps we can help you get to the finish line.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [MathJax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers. Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradient of the function is
$$\nabla f = (2x-2) \hat{i} + (2y-4)\hat{j} $$

Now, we require that

$$\nabla f || (\hat{i} + \hat{j})$$

$$\implies 2y-4 = 2x-2 \implies y = x+1$$

Comment: Can you please explain the reasoning on why you equated the two parts?

Comment: If a vector is parallel to $\vec{i} + \vec{j}$ it must be of the form $\lambda \vec{i} + \lambda \vec{j}$ - this means that the $x$ and $y$ components are always equal for such a vector